# Set input value to js function

Tags: javascript

I have a "Pay now" button on my site. To  set the product amount  I use the following Javascript :

```
<script>
var rupees=500;
window.PUM.setData(rupees);
</script>
```

This works with a fixed amount `500`  . I want my users to type their own amount in a text field and append the text value to the js function so I tried  the following but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
var rupees=document.getElementById("rs").value;
window.PUM.setData(rupees);
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your nearly there, you just need to attach that piece of code to the buttons onclick.

Comment: @Luca The chackout page doesnt load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to type something and then set that value, then you have to **wait until the user has typed something**.

Add an event listener which will fire when you want the code to save the value. For example, a click event on a nearby button, or a keypress event on the input itself.

Comment: I am now using `<input type="text"id="rs"onblur="goo()">

<script>
var rupees=document.getElementById( "rs" ).value;
window.PUM.setData(rupees);
</script>` but still doesn't work. thanks

Comment: You need to put the code **in a function** as well as calling the function!

Comment: Your suggestion was really helpful.  Thanks so much.  It works now.
`<script>
function goo()
{
    var rupees=document.getElementById("rs").value;          
window.PUM.setData(rupees);}
</script>`